# Google Sheets script editor: default timezone

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone, google-apps-script-editor

Is there a default timezone for Google Sheets script?

Is it dependent on the user setting, or account geo location, or it's always a fixed timezone?

For example when I issue the following I would like to know what the timezone would be:

```
new Date();
```

Preferably I would like to set this to either UTC or PST, if possible.

The script is supposed to be run by cron jobs via web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I ended up using moment.js in the script, which is much easier to work rather than Date which defaults to browser timezone. Hope this helps someone.

Moment.js has a much better control over timezone for parsing and showing dates.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

Editing my previous answer below.

You can now set/edit the timezone using the settings gear icon.

[image]

====================================================

**Previous answer**

You can change the timezone setting of the script in the manifest file.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

You can check updated timezone with this:

```
function check_Script_Time_Zone() {
  Logger.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default timezone of the script is the same as that of the containing Google Spreadsheet. Open the Google Spreadsheet, go to File and then Spreadsheet settings to see your default timezone.

You can setup cron jobs (time based triggers) in any timezone irrespective of your sheet timezone.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("fn").timeBased().atHour(1).inTimezone("PST").create()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked the spreadsheet setting and it's set to PST (GMT -8). But the script editor is being tested on a machine with a different timezone and at least for testing purposes on that machine we see a different timezone.